# HTML Bootstrap form: how to add spacing between elements, increase size of textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I inherited a small web project and I'm a bit lost of how to do two things:

1. Add more space between elements (padding?)
2. Increase the number of rows in my textarea (bottom element)

[image: Here's what it looks like currently]

And here is the code:

```
       <form class="contact-form" id="contactForm" action="php/contact2.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="senderName" id="firstName" placeholder="Fist Name" required>
          </div>
          
          
          
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="institution" id="inst" placeholder="Institution" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="city" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="state/province" name="stateprov" id="stateProv" placeholder="State/Province" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="zipost" id="zipost" placeholder="Zip/Postal" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Confirm Email" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="textarea" name="body" id="body" placeholder="Please describe your intended project(s), and how you plan to use the Apollo Platform." required>
          </div>
        </div>
        


        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-18">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-regular alignleft contact_button">Apply Now</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

How can I accomplish my two goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.form-row div { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.form-row input[type="textarea"] { height: 200px; }
```

Comment: Sorry it's been a very long time since I've done web programming... where do I put this code to try it out?

Comment: inside a .css file or directly in your html in a <style> tag : http://pastebin.com/LLW1kBqK

Comment: Oh awesome the pastebin seems to work! Quick follow-up: how could I center the "Apply Now" button? :)

Comment: button { text-align: center }

Comment: Sorry the button still isn't centered, not sure what's going on

Comment: It's beaucause your button have the class "alignleft", try this new pastebin : http://pastebin.com/nkgNLDpK

Comment: Still not centered unfortunately... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First there is no input type of textarea. The format for the textarea form elements is:

```
<textarea name="body" id="body" placeholder="Please describe your intended project(s), and how you plan to use the Apollo Platform." required></textarea>
```

If you want to add more height to a textarea you can do it with `style="height:100px"` or you can add the rows attribute `rows="5"` for example

If you want more padding you should be wrapping your labels and inputs in a block using bootstraps `form-group` class to stick with the automatic padded formats available to you in the bootstrap lib. You may also want to consider adding the bootstrap built in style to your form inputs and textarea which is `form-control`

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

`.col-md-12{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}`

for the first problem.

And for the second one why not use the `<textarea>` tag?